# Simplifying $\frac{D_2\sin2\theta_1 - D_1\sin2\theta_2}{D_1\cos2\theta_2 - D_2\cos2\theta_1}$ so that it can be calculated often

Tags: trigonometry

$$\tan(2\Delta\theta) = \frac{D_2\sin2\theta_1 - D_1\sin2\theta_2}{D_1\cos2\theta_2 - D_2\cos2\theta_1}$$

The goal is to get an expression for $\Delta\theta$ in shortest form as possible, as it is supposed to be calculated often.

Comment: What's wrong with taking arctangents?

Comment: You have to compute sine and cosine for both angles first, I'm looking fir a way to simplify right side of the expression.

Comment: I don't see that you can escape that for general  $D_i$ and without any linear relations between the $\theta_i.$